# Prevent Files from opening files with their parent apps

Tags: ios, files.app

In iOS 16 Files opens the app whose file you tap, when browsing the app's folder. For example, if I tap a video file in my downloads folder then Files will play the video in-app, but if I move that file into e.g. VLC's folder and tap it, Files will not play the file but instead launch VLC.

This is seldom desirable to me, for multiple reasons:

- The visual context of a third party app's (sub)folder is practically indistinguishable from other places in Files, so it's always unexpected behavior
- The third party app isn't suitable for opening the file, despite managing the file
- Unnecessary mental context switch for all file types that Files handles natively
- Unnecessary delay before viewing the contents

I know I can tap the eye* in the context menu of an item, but I still always forget because of #1, and even when I remember it gets tedious really fast.

**Is there some way of preventing Files from launching the app that owns the file when tapping the file, and instead have Files open the file in-app (be it an image, a PDF, video, or other type)?**

* I'm guessing they call it Preview or Quick Look, but apparently Files has no app settings, so I can't switch language to see what it's called.

Comment: Can you add a specific example to make this easier to understand?

Comment: What do you mean by “tap on a file and instead just show it itself?”  Can you give an example?

Comment: @nohillside I've added an example and reworded the question.

Comment: @Allan I've reworded the question. An example would be to play a video in the Files app despite the video itself residing in the folder of e.g. Acrobat Reader/VLC/OtherApp. Tapping the file just launches the app which constantly takes me by surprise and is often useless since the app is often a file management app that isn't suited for presentation, and even when the app is capable of presenting the file it often doesn't do that anyway (after launching).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there some way of preventing Files from launching other apps on a tap on a file,

**This is expected behavior.** When you tap on a file, iOS perceives that as you wanting to open that particular file. It’s no different from tapping on an App icon.  This behavior is consistent when using a mouse (what I am doing as I type this).  Clicking on the App or file once immediately launches it (or the associated app in Files).  It’s important to remember that mobile devices differ from desktops and the UI has been designed to accommodate that:  you double click on macOS to open something, while you single tap on iOS to do the same (even if using a BT mouse).

While you can’t change this behavior, there are, however, a couple of tweaks you can make to adjust the timing:

- **Hold Duration**. Found under Settings -> Accessibility -> Touch -> Touch Accommodations, you can adjust the delay time that the system will react to when you select something.  So, if you just tap the file for a brief moment, nothing will happen.
- **Touch Duration**.  Found under Settings -> Accessibility -> Touch -> Haptic Touch, you can set the speed at which actions, previews and contextual menus appear.  I believe the default is slow; I’ve set mine to “fast” to help eliminate the problem of accidental app opening/switching.

As far as “previewing” the contents of a file (that “eye” as you described) from within the Files app, this is only available for apps that provide Quick Look functionality (PDFs for example).  Third party App developers must provide the code as they would for macOS.  Without this, Files has no other choice but to open the associated App.

Finally, some of this comes down to user expectation and behavior.  I use Files extensively and I too, (in the beginning) experienced what you described.  By making a slight modification of how I interact with Files (i.e. a quick “flick” of my finger to scroll for example), I found that I could almost eliminate the accidental opening of files.

Comment: Well written answer, thanks. It seems to focus on accidental taps though which isn't my case; my taps are deliberate and it's my expectation that never matches the behavior which you describe as expected. I would agree it's intended behavior, but since I'm the user I can say with finality that it's almost never expected! Anyway, if there's nothing that can be done about it then that settles the question.

Comment: Also, unsupported Quick Look types will display a placeholder in Files, so the question of supported types doesn't quite matter with regard to preventing the launch of third party apps. I'd much rather see the placeholder than watch another useless app-launch :)